# Naming items by yourself (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf

What I am trying to make: I want to click on a button that lets me name my item. The item is then added to the listview.

So far the only way I can add an item is if I directly name it in the code.
Here is my code so far:

```
private void button_add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.Content = "randommmmm";
        list1.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you click the Button?

Comment: a window opens that gives me the option to name my item. So i could name my 1st item cat  and click on the button again and name the 2nd dog. sorry for the bad explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example that should give you the idea.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow: Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        popup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void txt_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            list1.Items.Add(txt.Text);
            txt.Text = string.Empty;
            popup.IsOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Window6" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>

        <ListView x:Name="list1" />

        <Popup x:Name="popup" Width="300" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}">
            <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" BorderThickness="2">
                <TextBox x:Name="txt" Margin="10" PreviewKeyDown="txt_PreviewKeyDown" />
            </Border>
        </Popup>

        <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Add" Click="Button_Click" />

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Clicking on the `Button` displays a `Popup` with a `TextBox` and when you press `[Enter]` the text in the `TextBox` is added to the `ListView`.

If you are serious about WPF and XAML I really recommend you to learn the [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) design pattern but that's another story :)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a TextBox to a property in your view model.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ItemName}" /> 

private string itemName;
public string ItemName 
{ 
    get { return itemName; } 
    set 
    {
        if (value == null || value == itemName) return;            

        itemName = value;
        NotifyOnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemName));
    } 
}
```

So you can use ItemName to create your item.

```
item.Content = ItemName;
```